# How do I use __dir__ without getting the realpath?

Tags: php, symlink

Let's pretend I have a symbolic link pointing to `/some/fake/location` from `/some/real/location`

In that hypothetical directory I have a file named `blah.php` which reads:

```
#!/usr/bin/php    
<?php echo __dir__; ?>
```

I then execute `blah.php` from the command line like so:

```
php /some/fake/location/blah.php
```

The output is

```
/some/real/location
```

How do I get the current PHP file's directory **without** resolving any symbolic links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After googling everywhere it seems that a million others need `__dir__` not to resolve symbolic links.  Unfortunately, however, the answer is that there is no answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since `__DIR__` resolves symlinks automatically, you may want use `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]` instead. It will returns the absolute pathname of the currently executing script.

Comment: Not quite what I want but I have already tried messing with that variable.  `blah.php` includes other files and I want those files to know what directory they're in. `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` only returns the full path of `blah.php`.

Comment: Does answer here help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580330/php-dirname-returns-symlink-path ?

Comment: Looks like the exact same question but with a completely different accepted answer.  `blah.php` has no idea if it's in a symbolic directory and is also clueless has to where it's stored.  `readlink(__dir__)` would also return the real directory instead of the wanted fake one.